# Not able to run project on Emulator with android studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, error-handling

[My Android studio Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hCyi.png)For some reason i cannot run any project with andoid studio on my andoid emulator, the buttons to quickly start the emulator and to run the project are greyed out.I updated android studio but everything is stil the same. Yesterday I was able to run any project, can somneone maybe told me what I maybe changed?

Answer (score 0):

With the lack of problem info provided from you,I can only tell you of a probable fix

First make sure you have flutter sdk and dart sdk installed (if you don't know how check see https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install

Then after making sure you have these installed,
go to: `file>project structure>modules>dependencies tab`

And make sure that dart and flutter support check-boxes are checked.

Then go to main.dart and right-click and see if you have the option `run main.dart` available now.